# Doxygen cannot include .aidl interfaces and enums to the documentation

Tags: java, android, markdown, doxygen, aidl

I have some .aidl files with intefaces and enums and want to add them to the API doc.
I added paths to INPUT and point **FILE_PATTERNS** with **.aidl** and **.java** and **EXTENSION_MAPPING** with **aidl=java**.

Then, I generate the doc and see nothing. But everything is OK when I add **public** keyword before **interface/enum**.

Seems doxygen expects **public** before **interface** or **enum** keywords, but this is the bad approach because android cannot parse them. I get `<interface, parcelable, enum or union> or AidlTokenTypes.IMPORT_KEYWORD expected, got 'public'` error here.

Is there any way to solve it?

**Update:**

doxygen: 1.9.6

Cannot provide an example because of the big private project

**EXTRACT_STATIC** = YES

**EXTRACT_PRIVATE** = NO

**Update 2**

Example: [github](https://github.com/golubevdmi/stackoverflow-issues/tree/master/77448988)

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Can you please give a small complete example so we can test it? maybe setting `EXTRACT+STATIC` or `EXTRACT_PRIVATE` does help.

Comment: @albert, updated the question. EXTRACT_PRIVATE might help but I think it can lead to unpredictable issues because the project has c++/java code with public/private interfaces which shouldn't be in the doc

Comment: Also, as I understand, enums and interfaces in java have public specifier by default. Why does doxygen consider it as non-public?

Comment: The current doxygen version is 1.9.8, maybe it is fixed there. I can understand that you cannot publish the project as it is a private project, but please try to create a small example that shows the problem. The `EXTRACT_PRIVATE` is indeed probably unwanted but was just put as test and  a way so we can get to the solution.

Comment: Despite a missing example, I found some code at https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_enums.asp and created a proposed patch https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/10402

Comment: @albert, I have added the example on github (see Update 2). Also, checked your solution. It works for enums, but not for interfaces (can suppose that your solution is about enums). But enums with private specifier are also added to the doc. I am not sure that it is a good solution

Comment: Good to hear that the fix for the enum has the required effect on your code base. The problem with the `interface` is a new problem and is illustrated in your example on github, though it would be much better / is required to create an issue in the doxygen issue tracker (so: please create at https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues a, small, self contained example (source+configuration file in a, compressed, tar or zip file) that allows us to reproduce the problem? Please don't add external links as they might not be persistent.) In the mean time I extended PR 10402 for interfaces.Please test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems missed case. Based on the @albert's comment, I created an issue https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/10434

Comment: The fix for the mentioned issue has been integrated in the master version of doxygen.